# Word VBA PageSetup.LeftMargin returns 9999999 while textbox is selected

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox

I am trying to align a selected textbox to the left margin of the active document. My document only has one section, so the ActiveDocument.Sections[0].PageSetup.LeftMargin (current section) widths should be the same as the ActiveDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin value.

I found a similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471564/word-vba-activedocument-pagewidth-9999999-in-working-document/). But it didn't help (other than adding to my understanding).

Here is my current C# code. I have tried variations (such as ActiveDocument.Sections 1), but nothing seems to work. It's almost like when a textbox shape is selected, the ActiveDocument.PageSetup margin values are set to 999999. Word is apparently saying "99999" because multiple values are possible, but I don't understand why. My document only has 1 section.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
    var testMe = wapp.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin; // equals 999999
    foreach (Word.Shape shape in sel.ShapeRange) {
      shape.Left = doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin; // align the textbox with left margin
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can align the shape to the left margin simply by assigning `.Left = 0`. Alse see [Shape.Left property Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape.left).
Try (C#):

```
foreach (Word.Shape shape in sel.ShapeRange) {
  shape.Left = 0; // align the textbox with left margin
}
```

As for defining PageSetup.PageWidth and PageSetup.LeftMargin, you can use something like (VBA):

```vb
Sub Align()
    Dim sh As Shape
    
    pw = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PageWidth
    lm = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin
    Debug.Print "PageWidth = " & pw, "LeftMargin = " & lm
    
    For Each sh In ActiveDocument.Range.ShapeRange
        Debug.Print vbLf, "================", vbLf
        section_number = sh.Anchor.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)
        Debug.Print "Shape '" & sh.Name & "' is in " & section_number & " Section"
        
        sec_width = ActiveDocument.Sections(section_number).PageSetup.PageWidth
        Debug.Print "Section " & section_number & " has Width = " & sec_width
        
        sec_lm = ActiveDocument.Sections(section_number).PageSetup.LeftMargin
        Debug.Print "Section " & section_number & " has Left = " & sec_lm
        
        Debug.Print "LeftMargin of the Section got from Shape's Anchor: " & sh.Anchor.Sections(1).PageSetup.LeftMargin
        Debug.Print "Shape '" & sh.Name & "' has Left = " & sh.Left
        
        sh.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
        sh.Left = 0 '0 is LeftMargin
    Next
End Sub
```

Prints:

```
PageWidth = 9999999         LeftMargin = 9999999

              ================            

Shape 'Text Box 1' is in 1 Section
Section 1 has Width = 595,3
Section 1 has Left = 85,05
LeftMargin of the Section got from Shape's Anchor: 85,05
Shape 'Text Box 1' has Left = 216

              ================            

Shape 'Text Box 2' is in 2 Section
Section 2 has Width = 841,9
Section 2 has Left = 56,7
LeftMargin of the Section got from Shape's Anchor: 56,7
Shape 'Text Box 2' has Left = 319,75
```

### Addition

Section's .PageSetup.LeftMargin diagnostic tool:

```vb
Sub Margins()
    Dim i As Integer
    With ActiveDocument
        Debug.Print "ActiveDocument has " & .Sections.Count & " sections"
        Debug.Print "The whole ActiveDocument has .PageSetup.LeftMargin = " & .PageSetup.LeftMargin
        For i = 1 To .Sections.Count
            Debug.Print "Section # " & i & " has .PageSetup.LeftMargin = " & .Sections(i).PageSetup.LeftMargin
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

In my test document with 3 sections it prints:

```
ActiveDocument has 3 sections
The whole ActiveDocument has .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 9999999
Section # 1 has .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 127,6
Section # 2 has .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 70,9
Section # 3 has .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 113,4
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That is clever, getting the section number from the text box anchor. I never thought of that. As far as I know, setting ```shape.Left = 0;``` aligns the shape with the edge of the page, not the left margin. (I use 0 for that all the time.) I will try out your anchor solution and report back!

Comment: Try setting the `Shape.RelativeHorizontalPosition` explicitly with `wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin` [WdRelativeHorizontalPosition enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrelativehorizontalposition) (added to the VBA code)

Comment: Wow! That was another brilliant idea! I guess I should always inspect the ```RelativeHorizontalPosition``` value before setting shape.Left values. I saw that my shape RHP was "column" (I suppose the width of the current text column). I used ```shape.Left=0;``` and that aligned to the left margin. I used ```shape.Width = doc.PageSetup.TextColumns[1].Width;``` and that made the textbox full width. Yay! It is amazing that someone from the other side of the world has helped me. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question - do you know why the PageSetup.LeftMargin and .PageWidth values are 99999? Does my document really have two sections with two different margin widths? I guess it only needs to have two sections (regardless of widths) to force a 99999 value. That is possible. Thank you again.

Comment: Check the `ActiveDocument.Sections.Count`

Comment: @Kevin - it is because you have a shape selected. 99999 means undefined/unable to determine in the current context.

Comment: @АлексейР I kind of did check the document by opening the header/footer and visually looking at the labels "Header Section 1", etc. I do not recall seeing a "Header Section 2" anywhere, so I assumed that I had only one section in the document. I will try it out with a fresh document when I have time. Thank you again for your help. I will also test to see if selecting a textbox always forces a 99999 value. Thank you for your help.